# Finding out what locked a site collection

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, read-only, quota

We've had an instance twice now in which a client sharepoint site collection is going into read-only mode. We have no quotas set, the health of the farm is in overall good condition, and we haven't applied unusual patches. They're a very cookie-cutter install.

We were unable to remove the read-only state in Central Administration (CA -> App Management -> Configure Quotas & Locks), and the two methods below did NOT work.

```
Set-SPSite -Identity <url> -Lockstate Unlock
```

- or-

```
stsadm.exe -o setsitelock -url <url> -lock none
```

However, `stsadm.exe` would confirm that the site was locked when using the `-o getsitelock` query. The only way to remove it was a rather heavy handed server restart on the IIS/SP server, however when this happened the second time around we found that `iisreset /noforce /restart` fixed it.

The logs give nothing really helpful -- even when manually executing a site collection lock on a test site I saw nothing in the logs indicating I had applied it except when I turned up the verbosity level. The question I have is: What conditions would cause a site to lock itself? What might we be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: what type of lock site get? is this only site collection in the web application? what error you get when you trying to unlock it? any backup jobs running before this site get locked? any workflow / custom timer job running on the web app? Enable the Verbose logging and check from all servers in the farm.